# How to transfer passwords between client and server in a more secure way?

Tags: passwords

I am making an mobile application that interacts with a server. I want to figure out a way to transfer passwords safely. If I send the passwords in plain text or hashed form, it can be sniffed. How to send passwords in a more secure way from the client to the server?

Comment: encrypt the transmission so that it cannot be sniffed?

Comment: The literature on password exchange is vast, and you can find a lot of good practices for secure application development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTTPS, or any other form of TLS connection.

HTTPS provides encryption and authentication, and you need both for a secure connection. It makes sniffing anything on the connection impossible.

Comment: >TLS1.2 preferrably... avoid ssl2,ssl3,tls1.0 and tls1.1

Answer (score 1):

To keep passwords as safe as possible, even if your server is comprised (even if one of the administrators acts as an attacker), use a protocol that does not transfer the user's password and that even does not transfers a hash of the password at user authentication time.

This is possible with the Secure Remote Password (SRP) protocol :
http://srp.stanford.edu/

With this SRP protocol, an exchange of 2 random numbers (1 sent from the user to the server and 1 sent from the server to the user) is enough to authenticate the user (as the owner of the password) and to establish a secure channel (as SSL/TLS does). Of course these 2 random numbers contain some authentication information, but this information is mixed with random numbers in such a way that, for an eyedropper, the 2 numbers exchanged are just precisely 2 random numbers. See RFC 2945 or the original paper from Tom Wu, and the SRP-6 update from Tom Wu.

Not that a hash ("verifier") needs to be transfered once, at password set up time, in order to be stored on the server. (It could of course become the target of a brute force attack). After that, only random numbers are exchanged for authentication, revealing nothing more about the user's password (and preventing a replay attack).

Comment: With SRP your server needs to know the cleartext password, so if the server is compromised, the passwords wouldm too…